# Join SQL query doesn't work

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have a table `app_form_data_audit_trail` which I need to join to another table `app_fd_listofcomponents`.

-The foreign key needs first to be extracted from a column collating some other data before getting the 1st table joined with the 2nd one.

-Some records from the first table needs to be filtered out.

I made the following sql query but getting error. I created a sqlfiddle [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/73bee/3) for troubleshooting purpose..

Thanks for your help :-)

```
SELECT DATETIME
    ,username
    ,CASE 
        WHEN locate('operation', DATA) > 0
            THEN substring_index(substring_index(DATA, '"operation":"', - 1), '"', 1)
        ELSE 0
        END AS operation
    ,CASE 
        WHEN locate('operation', DATA) > 0
            THEN substring_index(substring_index(DATA, '"opdetails":"', - 1), '"', 1)
        ELSE 0
        END AS opdetails
    ,CASE 
        WHEN locate('operation', DATA) > 0
            THEN substring_index(substring_index(DATA, '"componentName":"', - 1), '"', 1)
        ELSE 0
        END AS componentid
    ,CASE 
        WHEN locate('operation', DATA) > 0
            THEN substring_index(substring_index(DATA, '"package":"', - 1), '"', 1)
        ELSE 0
        END AS package
FROM app_form_data_audit_trail
WHERE DATA LIKE "%Operation%"
INNER JOIN app_fd_listofcomponents ON app_form_data_audit_trail.componentid = app_fd_listofcomponents.id
```

Comment: `JOIN` is part of the `FROM` clause.  The `WHERE` follows the `FROM` clause.

Comment: Thanks for your answer but how should I correct my query please ?

Comment: @CSA75 you need to move your `INNER JOIN` line above the `WHERE`. Your syntax is incorrect

Comment: You have a number of questions about syntax errors. Find justification in an intro/manual/reference for exactly what you write before you run code or post a question.

Answer (score 0):

FROM app_form_data_audit_trail
INNER JOIN app_fd_listofcomponents ON app_form_data_audit_trail.componentid = app_fd_listofcomponents.id 
WHERE DATA LIKE "%Operation%"

Comment: Thanks Pandi, I corrected as follows but now I'm facing another issue..

Comment: Thanks Pandi ! I corrected as follows but now I'm facing another issue..here is the error message returned by phpmyadmin : "Unknown column app_form_data_audit_trail.componentid" in ON clause.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to all, Finally I came to write the query as follows and it works !

```
SELECT
app_form_data_audit_trail.datetime,
app_form_data_audit_trail.username,
app_form_data_audit_trail.data,
app_fd_listofcomponents.c_component,
substring_index(substring_index(app_form_data_audit_trail.data,'"operation":"',-1),'"',1) AS operation,
substring_index(substring_index(app_form_data_audit_trail.data,'"opdetails":"',-1),'"',1) AS opdetails,
substring_index(substring_index(app_form_data_audit_trail.data,'"package":"',-1),'"',1) AS package
FROM app_form_data_audit_trail
JOIN app_fd_listofcomponents
ON app_form_data_audit_trail.data LIKE CONCAT ('%',app_fd_listofcomponents.id,'%')
```